# How to pass and GET session through URL?

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've one variable called numbers which I'm use within a session to identify a user. The link should be like index.php?number=1234567890, where number is the session name to be set and 123456789 is a user id. Can you explain how to do it "Pass through URL and SET as a var"?

```
index.php?number=1234567890
```

GET[???]

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from `$_GET` as follows in your index.php

```
$number=$_GET['number'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is accessible in your code as `$_GET['number']`

Answer (score 0):

To access any GET variables, use `$_GET['varname']`

Rather than pass a GET variable everytime you redirect, consider using a cookie (`setcookie` function and `$_COOKIE` variable) or session variables (`start_session` function and `$_SESSION` variable)